# before_action on all pages but one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to redirect all pages to my `groups` page when a group isn't yet created. I've got a `before_action` in my application_controller which does this for me. But, obviously, gets stuck in a loop because he's checking it on the groups page aswell. Can I use `:except` for the groups page? If so, How?

I've tried:

```
before_action :isGroupPresent, except: :groups
before_action :isGroupPresent, except: :group
before_action :isGroupPresent, except: [:group]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `except` parameter only accepts methods, not controller names.

You could check for `params[:controller] == 'groups'` in your `isGroupPresent` method and change actions accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **skip_before_action** in your GroupsController

skip_before_action :isGroupPresent, only: [:new, :create]

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters